# Creating different tables in hbase for every different url in my seed file in nutch?

Tags: hbase, nutch

I'm using nutch 2.1 integrated with Hbase 0.92.1. When I fetch data from websites all of the data is written in only one  table in Hbase and this is my problem. The table's name is "webpage".

Is there a way for every different URL in my seed file to be created a new table?

Answer (score 0):

I found it.In nutch 2.0 threre is the so-called crawlId for the prefix of the name of the table :).

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar functionality, but failed to understand how crawlId could be used without some hacking.

What wasn't immediately clear is that inject can take a -crawlId  parameter (eg. nutch inject seed.txt -crawlId firstSeed)...This will then create a separate table in HBase called firstSeed_webpage for that entire .txt file.

For the above use case it would be fairly straightforward to write a bash script which could read off the .txt line by line and give each URL a new crawlId.

!!!!! (Note: For all commands related to that crawl you should include the -crawlId  flag to denote which table you intend on using.)